# How to change language keyboard in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, keyboard, registry

Is there any way to set language keyboard (ex. US keyboard to German keyboard), by internal registry key or by code in Windows 10 OS? (without rebooting)

I have proved it changing the registry key "Keyboard Layout/preload/1" but it doesn't work.

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Maybe [How to change System Key Board Default input language(registry entry) using c# code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/65e80962-9727-45d4-a208-49a3437f376a/how-to-change-system-key-board-default-input-languageregistry-entry-using-c-code?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646289(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant that's helps me a lot, thank you so much